# Panda.Read_CSV Usecols not print output as a list in Python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why when I am trying to print the following code...

```
import pandas
import csv

passengersid=pandas.read_csv('test.csv', usecols=['PassengerId'])

print(passengersid)
```

...I am getting this:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ff4w.png)

I am trying to get a simple list of values (without indexes of values and not a table) from the first (PassengersID) column in one csv file and then iterate and use it in the other csv file along with other data.

Comment: Try: `passengersid['PassengerID'].tolist()`. To answer your question, the `read_csv()` function returns a DataFrame.

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

You are reading a data frame with the `read_csv` command.

```
col_one_list = passengersid['PassengerId'].tolist()

col_one_arr = passengersid['PassengerId'].to_numpy()
```

this will give you a list or an array as you need

Comment: Minor correction for you mate:`read_csv` *reads* a CSV file and *returns* a DataFrame.

Comment: Sorry big man,  and while I was typing I did not see your answer...  thanks for helping out.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, worked like a charm :)